# Xcode: what is this colour? (settings table view background colour)

Tags: ios, xcode

I would like to replicate the colour that can be seen in a grouped Table View, however in the developer colour palette there is no matching colour. Any idea if this is already a preset somewhere?

[image]

Comment: What do you want? Its not a preset. Do you want its color code?

Comment: use color meter in mac to get the color code!!!!

Comment: Have you tried hex color picker for xcode?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Interface Builder, rather than pressing on the large colour block, if you click on the up/down blue arrows on the right, you will be presented with built-in options.

Click arrows on right hand side in blue:

[image]

This will display this list:

[image]

I believe you are looking for "Group Table View Background Color".

To set this programatically, you can use:

**Swift:**

```
UIColor.groupTableViewBackgroundColor()
```

**Objective-C**

```
[UIColor groupTableViewBackgroundColor]
```

Answer (score 3):

Not a direct answer to you question, but if you want to pick and save any color on your screen, you can do this:

[image]

Use the color picker tool at the bottom of the "Colors" panel and just drag your mouse over something that is visible on your screen (doesn't have to be within Xcode). When you are done you can save the color in the "Color Palettes" tab.